# Find the first value greater than user specified value from a map container

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map container. How to return the first value greater than the user-specified search value by using find_if as follows:

```
std::map<string, int>::iterator it = find_if(Mymap.begin(), Mymap.end(), ......
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is std::find_if absolutely needed?  If not, Mark B's answer is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a lambda:

```
int n = MYVALUE;
auto it = std:: find_if(Mymap.begin(), Mymap.end(),
                        [n](const std::pair<std::string, int> & x) -> bool
                        { return x.second > n; }
                       );
```

(If the value is fixed you can put it directly inside the lambda body. For C++14 and later, the lambda capture can be `[n = MYVALUE]` and you don't need a separate outer variable `n`.)

With a predicate:

```
struct Finder
{
  Finder(int n_) : n(n_) { }
  int n;
  bool operator()(const std::pair<std::string, int> & x) const
  {
    return x.second > n;
  }
};

auto it = std::find_if(Mymap.begin(), Mymap.end(), Finder(MYVALUE));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my compiler doesn't support lamda function.

Comment: How old is your compiler? Use the predicate then. It does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your solution will work if you change bool operator< to bool operator(). Thank you!

Comment: I have added code to print the find output. Need to assign output of find_if to an interator.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want to be doing a linear search for any item with a value greater than your criteria through the container?

It would probably be better to also keep a separate index of sorted values that you could call `upper_bound` on, performing in logarithmic time rather than linear in the number of elements. Alternately look into `boost::multi_index` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For C++03 you need to provide comparator object, or deal with some tricky bindings:

```
typedef map<string, int>::value_type Value;

struct Comp
{
    Comp(int v) : m_v(v) { }

    bool operator()(const Value& v) const
    {
        return v.second > m_v;
    }

    int m_v;
};

void f()
{
    map<string, int> Mymap;
    map<string, int>::iterator it = find_if(Mymap.begin(), Mymap.end(), Comp(42));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the book of B.Stroustrup very useful when it comes to STL features.
And he proposes this code:

```
bool gt_42 (const pair <const string ,int>& r )
{
    return  r.second >42 ;
}
void f (map <string,int >& m )
{
    typedef map <string ,int >:: const_iterator MI ;
    MI i = find_if (m.begin (), m.end (), gt_42 );
    // ...
}
```

From chapter "A Tour of the Standard Library" (available in .pdf file) of ["The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition"](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html)