# How can I make std::find_if and std::map work together using some boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-fusion, boost-phoenix

This question is inspired from [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335546/find-the-first-value-greater-than-user-specified-value-from-a-map-container) which poses this question:

> Find the first value greater than user specified value from a map container

which can be solved in several ways. A typical C++03 solution defines a dedicated function (or functor) and pass it to `std::find_if` as third argument.

In C++11, one can avoid defining a *dedicated* function (or functor), and can instead make use of `lambda` as:

```
auto it = std:: find_if(m.begin(), mp.end(), 
                    [n](const std::pair<std::string, int> & x) -> bool
                       { return x.second > n; }
                   );
```

which is [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335546/find-the-first-value-greater-than-user-specified-value-from-a-map-container/7335623#7335623).

I'm still looking for a short and cool solution. If it were a vector, then I just learnt a cool solution which makes use of `Boost.Phoenix` and the solution becomes very concise ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rUmzH)):

```
std::vector<int> v = ...;
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), arg1 > 4);
```

Here `arg1` is a functor object defined in `boost::phoenix::arg_names` namespace, and the expression `arg1>4` evaluates to another  functor which then gets passed to `std::find_if`.

A quick test is ([ideone](http://ideone.com/rUmzH)),

```
std::cout<< (arg1 > 9)(v) << std::endl; //prints 0 if as v > 9 is false, else 1

//or store the functor first and then use it
const auto & f = arg1 > 9;
std::cout<<  f(v) << std::endl; //prints 0 if as v > 9 is false, else 1
```

---

My question is, I want to solve the map problem, in a similar way. Is there any such solution? Something like:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(),mp.end(), (???).second > n); //m is std::map
```

Or,

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(),mp.end(), at<1>(arg1) > n);  //m is std::map
```

For it to work, the expression `at<1>(arg1) > 2` has to evaluate to a functor which takes `const std::pair &` as argument. My gut feelings tells me that boost has this solution. :-)

Comment: Do you want to find only the values (in which case http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html is the answer) or the iterator to the whole key,value pair where value satisfied the predicate?

Comment: @Cubbi: That is not the answer if that doesn't work with `std::find_if` which returns an iterator of the map.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't know if std::find_if is required.  If not, I'd go with  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/upper_bound/ which should be faster, and only one simple line of code.

Comment: @Mooing: Please read the doc which says `Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the container whose *key* compares greater than x (using the container's comparison object).` and here I want ot  compare *values*, not *keys*.

Comment: @Nawaz: whoa, my bad.  I didn't obvserve that you were finding the greatest value.  std::find_if then.

Comment: Of course if you wanted to make such queries frequently, I would advise either a BiMap or a MultiIndex :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, Boost.Fusion and Boost.Phoenix have exactly what you want built-in.

If one includes the necessary header to [adapt `std::pair<>` as a conforming Fusion sequence](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/std__pair.html), then one can use Phoenix's lazy version of `boost::fusion::at_c<>` to access `std::pair<>::first` or `std::pair<>::second` (be sure to `#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>`).

```
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using phx::arg_names::arg1;

auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), phx::at_c<1>(arg1) > n);
```

---

**EDIT:** Full sample, tested with VC++ 2010 SP1 + Boost 1.47.0:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/core.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    using phx::arg_names::arg1;

    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    m["foo"]    = 1;
    m["bar"]    = 2;
    m["baz"]    = 3;
    m["qux"]    = 4;
    m["quux"]   = 5;
    m["corge"]  = 6;
    m["grault"] = 7;
    m["garply"] = 8;
    m["waldo"]  = 9;
    m["fred"]   = 10;
    m["plugh"]  = 11;
    m["xyzzy"]  = 12;
    m["thud"]   = 13;

    int const n = 6;
    auto it = std::find_if(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), phx::at_c<1>(arg1) > n);
    if (it != m.cend())
        std::cout << it->first << '\n'; // prints "fred"
}
```

Comment: Please post a full working and tested solution. I don't wanna say that it doens't compile or doens't work. Though, I'm trying to do what you suggested.

Comment: Alright. I tried compiling it, and it failed at compilation : http://ideone.com/EgALC

Comment: @Nawaz : Ideone has Boost 1.39; Boost.Phoenix became a standalone library only in Boost 1.47. Try it locally.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work at ideone which is using I think older version of ideone. But then I think that is not the problem. My doubt is that if `at_c<1>(arg1) > n` doesn't evaluated to a functor object which takes `std::pair` as argument, then how can it work?

Comment: @Nawaz : `phoenix::at_c<1>(arg1) > n` **does** evaluate to a functor taking a `std::pair<>` argument. Here is your sample with corrected includes (for old versions of Boost): http://ideone.com/8myyc