# Boost phoenix actor as a fusion callable object

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-fusion, boost-phoenix

I was wondering if it was possible to create callable phoenix actors and use them in fusion sequences.
Given the following source:

```
struct FusionStruct
{
    void Doit() const{std::cout << "Doit" << std::endl;}
};

struct FusionCaller
{
    template <typename T> void operator()(T& x) const
    {
        x.second.Doit();
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<int, FusionStruct> > FusionMap_t;
    FusionMap_t fmap(boost::fusion::make_pair<int>(FusionStruct()));
    boost::fusion::for_each(fmap, FusionCaller());
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected.
But since I can create polymorphic callable actors in phoenix like this:

```
auto p = (boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1 * boost::phoenix::placeholders::arg1);
// int and double are fine
std::cout << p(2,2) << std::endl;
std::cout << p(2.0,2.0) << std::endl;
```

I was wondering  if I can use phoenix to get rid of my FusionCaller struct. Like this:
`fusion::for_each(fmap, /* some magic phoenix expression*/);`

So is this possible at all with phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>

using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

fusion::for_each(fmap, boost::phoenix::at_c<1>(arg1).DoIt() );
```

Comment: On my VS2010 I get an error `error C2780: 'const boost::phoenix::detail::expression::function_eval<boost::phoenix::stl::at_impl,A0,A1>::type boost::phoenix::at(const A0 &,const A1 &)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided`

Comment: Which version of Fusion you're using?

Comment: @mkaes: Ohh.. I can't even test it. Anyway, I had asked similar question once, now my problem is working. Maybe you should look into this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337414/how-can-i-make-stdfind-if-and-stdmap-work-together-using-some-boost-library

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `phoenix::at_c<1>` rather than `phoenix::at<1>`.